# Why is $n\log(n^2 + 1)=O (n\log n)$ instead of $O(n\log n^2)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Why is $n\log(n^2 + 1)=O (n\log n)$ instead of big $O(n\log n^2)$?

I thought all I needed to do was drop the constant and just write the big O of what remains. How did $O(n\log n)$ came out of $n\log(n^2+1)$? I'm not sure what kind of prerequisite knowledge I need to know to figure out the big O of a function. Some functions are obvious to get the Big O but some are not so easy.

Comment: Hint: It's not "instead of."

Comment: My thought process says O(nlogn^2) but when my professor went over in class. She says it is O(nlogn) but I don't understand why.

Comment: $O(n\log n^2)$ is true, too, but $O(n\log n)$ is preferred because it is simpler.

Comment: How did they exponent of 2 disappear? Because you need to put it in the front or do exponent automatically disapppear?

Comment: There is a law of logarithms that says $\log a^x = x \log a$. Combine that with the fact that constants disappear in big-O notation.

Comment: Oh the law of logarithms dictates that. Thanks for the nice information, Tony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$O(\log n^2)$ and $O(\log n)$ are the same complexity class, because $\log n^2=2\log n$ and constant factors don't matter for big-O growth rates.

(Therefore $O(n\log n^2)$ means the same thing as $O(n\log n)$, too).

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you treated n log(n^2 + 1) as n and logn^2 + 1. n is big O(n) and logn^2 + 1 is big O(2logn). O(2logn) is just logn because the constant don't matter. putting the big O together is nlogn. Is that how you got the O(nlogn).

Comment: x @Nicholas: It is not true that "$O(2\log n)$ is just $\log n$". What is true is that $\log n$ is $O(2\log n)$ (and $2\log n$ is $O(\log n)$), but not the other way around. The verb "is" is not symmetric for big-O estimates. It may help to think of "$O(2\log n)$" as an adjective rather than a noun -- so you can say "Kermit the Frog is green", but not "green is Kermit the Frog".

Comment: Why do you put the exponent in the front? I never understood quite why this is so

Comment: x @Nicholas: $\log x^y=y\log x$ is a general fact about logarithms. When $y$ is an integer you can derive it from $\log ab = \log a+\log b$ by induction.

Comment: It is not true the other way around for both examples: 2logn is not O(logn ) and logn is not O(2logn) you mean?

Comment: x @Nicholas: $2\log n$ is both $O(2\log n)$ and $O(\log n)$, and $\log n$ is also both $O(2\log n)$ and $O(\log n)$. However it is wrong to say "$O(\log n)$ is $2\log n$" or "$O(\log n)$ is $\log n$", or anything of that sort.

Comment: Oh I see there are many answers for it.

Answer (score 3):

$$
O(n \log n^2) \approx O(2n \log n) \approx O(n\log n)
$$

Comment: Approximations on the asymptotics are not necessary. By definition of Big-O we have equality.

Comment: I should been clear
$$
n \log (n^2 + 1 ) \approx O(n \log n^2) ...
$$

Comment: Still not incorrect, but a bit misleading. I prefer to think of complexity classes as sets. By definition, Big-O is an upper bound. So either this condition holds (for all $n \geq k$, for some $k$): $nlog(n^{2}+1) \leq C*|n log(n^{2})|$; or this condition does not hold. It just doesn't make sense to talk about approximations here. :-)